# Should this user be blocked or removed from the post of moderator

Tags: discussion, tags, moderators

This person with the name of Mr. Alien has been tagging questions related to Hinduism as mythology. Who gives him such authority and on what basis is he doing this? Can anyone explain. The user profile is [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/124/mr-alien).

And here's the post he edited the tags ...

[What exactly is the basis/reason behind calling Hindu epics such as Ramayana and Mahabharata as myths/mythology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/what-exactly-is-the-basis-reason-behind-calling-hindu-epics-such-as-ramayana-and)

Comment: I think am not the right person to answer this ... So I will wait for another user who understands(hopefully) that why I retagged.

Comment: please provide links to the posts which were edited unnecessarily with [tag:mythology] tag.(_according to you_)

Comment: God I can't downvote, I don't think adding mythology to that question is any wrong, its the askers perspective, and you can change that with valid answers. Thirdly we all know there are modifications done in our scriptures, you will find different stories in different places, there is a small amount of myth there.

Answer (score 7):

I think I should probably speak up, since I'm the creator of the  [mythology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) tag; I created it on the first day the site was in private beta while asking [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/62/36).  Here's the thing: the word "myth" has two uses in English:

1. A pejorative usage, referring to "a widely held but false belief or idea"
2. A non-pejorative usage, "a traditional story, especially one concerning the early history of a people or explaining some natural or social phenomenon, and typically involving supernatural beings or events."

The word "mythology", however, only has one meaning and that's a meaning that's related to the non-pejorative usage of the word myth.

So when we tag a question about a Hindu story as [mythology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology), we're not saying that the story is false or fictional.  We're simply saying that the question concerns one of the "stories that are part of Hindu religious beliefs", as the tag description I wrote says.

And let me be clear: I think Hindu mythology is absolutely true.  I don't think the stories found in Hindu scripture are fictional or metaphorical, I think they literally took place the way they're described.  So by using the word "mythology" I am definitely not expressing any skepticism about whether our stories are true.

Concerning whether Mr. Alien should be blocked, I think there's only one punishment appropriate to everything he's done to the site: elect him as one of the permanent mods when we graduate out of public beta!  Keep up the good work, Mr. Alien!

Comment: haha thanks for appreciating... :) and its not just me, credit goes to all other active users as well who flags, reviews and carries on similar moderation activities on the site after earning privileges...

Comment: If the OP does not add Mythology tag to his/her question, then y should someone add it? Its OP choice if he can add or not.

Comment: @Sandeep No, things on Stackexchange sites aren't entirely up to the OP - that's the whole point of a community editing process.  The purpose of tags is to classify questions on the site, so that if someone is interested in Hindu mythology they can look through the questions in the mythology tag.  So it doesn't matter if they OP chose to tag it with mythology, if that's the topic the question falls under then that's how it should be tagged.

Comment: By this logic all the questions fall under Mythology tag(if i tag them will you accept). The way we look at us is important if we add Mythology to Ramayana it doesn't feel good . You can argue Mythology here means something different but at the end it means based on Myth. And to edit a question only to add a tag which may be relevant is not good. As a reputed user i think you may understand this.

Comment: @Sandeep No, not all questions on this site fall under mythology.  There are plenty of questions on the site about Hindu philosophy, Hindu practices, etc. But yes, if you see any question on a "story that is part of Hindu religious beliefs", as the tag description says, please feel free to add the tag.  And it's absolutely fine to edit a question just to modify the tags, if the right tags haven't been assigned.  In any case, I'm not using the word mythology in an unusual way.  This is the standard dictionary definition of the term.

Comment: Using a mythology tag does give the first impression that the story is false or fictional.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan `dharmo rakshati rakshitaha` I feel pity on u , how you take pride in calling your religion Myth. [In this answer](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20/4780) you told you are *Sri Vaishnava (an Iyengar to be precise)*, lol?.

Comment: @Sandeep I take pride in calling Hindu mythology 100% correct.  In any case, please stop removing the mythology tag from questions.

Comment: @Sandeep I am an Iyengar, and moreover an Iyengar who believes that all stories found in Hindu mythology are true.  Again, the word mythology is unconnected to the pejorative meaning of the word myth.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan just rename the tag to something good .

Comment: @Sandeep It's fine the way it is.  Whenever someone hovers over or clicks on the tag, they will see the description "stories that are part of Hindu religious beliefs".  And like I said, the word mythology only has one meaning in the English language, and that's connected to the non-pejorative use of the word myth.

Comment: I seem to have stumbled here from the [opposite PoV](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12439/how-does-western-model-of-human-evolution-fit-with-vedic-literature/13546#comment32663_13546). The discussion above makes sense as a way of establishing individual beliefs. However, as a community, are all answers on this website meant to assume that Hindu texts and beliefs are *literally true*? A large body of Indic research treats these subjects as symbols or metaphors, and would have to be discarded.

Comment: @Jedi No, we welcome people of all viewpoints here.  This is a question and answer site about Hinduism, not a Hindu website.  Answers on this site are just supposed to explain what Hinduism has to say on a given subject, they do not need to assume that Hinduism is true.  Answers which quote Western Indologists are absolutely fine on this site. In fact I've quoted Western Indologists myself, even though personally I believe that Hindu scripture is literally true.

Comment: Thanks [@Keshav Srinivasan](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/36/keshav-srinivasan). In that case, isn't the [history tag](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) the one that is misused more often-- is it appropriate to tag `history` when asking questions about the text of the Mahabharat, Ramayana ... ?

Comment: @Jedi Let me be clear, this site is open to non-Hindus, but that doesn't mean that the tagging on this site necessarily has to be neutral in how it categorizes things.  If a Hindu believes (like I do) that the Ramayana and Mahabharata are about historical events, there's nothing wrong with them tagging questions about those texts with the history tag

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, not worried about the site being open to non-Hindus. I'm not yet clear about when the `history` tag should be used vs when the `mythology` tag. Sorry if I'm missing something basic-- I've just joined StackExchange this month and am looking to learn more about how these knowledge communities work. It sounds like it is up to the poster's POV, which seems arbitrary. I read a large number of meta posts on this subject, but this isn't made explicit anywhere that I could see.

Comment: @Jedi When dealing with a Hindu story, the mythology tag should always be used.  But if on top of that, the poster wants to also include the history tag, they're free to do so.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan The etymology of the term does not conform to what you said - _The word "mythology", however, only has one meaning and that's a meaning that's related to the non-pejorative usage of the word myth._, Here is what [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mythology#Etymology) has to say _From its earliest use in reference to a collection of traditional stories or beliefs,[14] mythology implied the falsehood of the stories being described_

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Moreover the general use of the term is "study of myths" and **myth** in general means "fictional" and not just "story". Can't we use the actual terms like itihas, ancient-history or purana?

Comment: Though i understand the reasoning behind using it - **to help people search in general the stories in our scriptures**, but the term has acquired a negative connotation.

Comment: the world mythology simply means a collection of myths. the word myth has 2 meanings. so mythology means a collection of {fact, fiction}. it might have only one connotation in some people's minds, but in a LOT of others, it refers to made up stories/allegories etc.