# 'Mythology' tag - Nth discussion

Tags: discussion, tags

Myth definition:

> a traditional story, especially one concerning the early history of a
> people or explaining some natural or social phenomenon, and typically
> involving supernatural beings or events.
>
> a widely held but false belief or idea.

Mythology:

> collection/study of myths

So, @KeshavSrinivasan's [comment](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352/my-concern-about-the-use-of-mythology-tag) :

> And by the way, while the word myth has these two disparate meanings
> in English, the word mythology has only one meaning and that is
> related to the non-pejorative usage of the word myth, i.e. "a
> traditional story, especially one concerning the early history of a
> people or explaining some natural or social phenomenon, and typically
> involving supernatural beings or events."

doesn't seem to have google's blessing, since mythology is just a collection of myths, which could mean collection of facts, or collection of lies.

Suppose there was a word called **'blakawaka'**, which had these 2 meanings:

> 1. something that happened in the past that people believe
> 2. something that did not happen in the past that people believe

and **blakawakology**:

> collection/study of blakawakas

Will we now use the blakawakology tag for questions asking about mahabharata/ramayana ?

Comment: This question is not needed now as you have posted the same thing as an answer to linked question.