# @Sandeep. Don't remove Mythology Tag while editing questions

Tags: discussion

I appreciate your efforts of improving  grammar and format of some questions and answers but why do remove [mythology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) for questions asking Puranic Stories? This clearly conflicts with author's intent.

Please see [My concern about the use of mythology tag](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/352/3500), [Keshav's answer about meaning of word Mythology](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/293/3500), and [What exactly is the basis/reason behind calling Hindu epics such as Ramayana and Mahabharata as myths/mythology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2797/2995).

Thanks for editing and my point here is just to inform about [mythology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) tag.

Answer (score -2):

Don't worry.

I am banned from editing questions because you and user named s.v rejected  my most of the edits.

**Mythology tag**- Mythology means based on a myth(1st defination and largely used, no one cares about other definitions).

I have seen Mythology tag being used where very specific tags are used like Ramayana, Rama, etc. but what is the use of a very very broader tag (Mythology).

I also talked about this to a moderator but he is not ready to listen (maybe greedy for badge , points).

**BYE**

Comment: Your act of retaliation on my questions is not fair. Not only me another user too rejected your edit. An edit needs opinion of two users.

Comment: Only 2 users were in suggested review queue you and s.v .  You reviewed nearly 15-16 edits and s.v nearly 5-6 . Iam not retaliating im just answering because you named specifically me.

Comment: If you check properly, i accepted many of your edits many times. Questions related to "mythology" tag has been rejected because user Mr green added them previously and this was already discussed on meta. You retaliated by downvoting two  questions of me.

Comment: @Sandeep I understand your frustration with the use of [mythology](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) tag but it's already used on [564 questions, as of now](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags) and it was in use before you or I joined this site. So I don't think the clean-up that you are trying to do will do any good to the site. It will only cause further confusion. Besides, most users on the site already know what exactly the tag means.

Comment: @Sandeep A month ago I tried to point you in the right direction [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/15189?m=28293513#28293513) in chat, maybe you missed that. If you want to create a tag synonym for mythology, feel free to suggest [here](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/470/2995), I suggested one [here](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/470/the-one-tag-cleanup-post-to-rule-them-all#comment1563_495).

Comment: @Sandeep To answer your question, why the need for a broader mythology tag, if you are in to software programming, mythology-ramayana tags are similar to [javascript-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+jquery) tags (one is the parent of the other). A user might want to search on all [mythology](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) questions instead of a subset like [ramayana](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ramayana) or [mahabharata](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mahabharata).

Comment: @Sandeep  At a high level, I think questions tagged with mythology are very different from questions tagged [moksha](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moksha), [brahman](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brahman), [vedanta](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vedanta) etc. hence the need for a separate and broader mythology tag.

Comment: @sv. that is the thing, *If a question is tagged as Jquery it is not necessary to tag it as javascript* and the same way *if a question is tagged as **ramayana** or **mahabharata** then why mythology tag is added*.

Comment: @Sandeep Like I said, it's merely a [classification method](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/tagging). If I want to learn more about Krishna's ancestry I would simply search for [mythology+krishna](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology+krishna), I don't really care if it's from Mahabharata or Srimad-Bhagavatam. But if I simply searched for [krishna](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/krishna) it would give me all of Krishna's Bhagavad-Gita teachings also. So I believe mythology tag is definitely useful.